# Queue two sets of each() functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, recursion, queue, each

I am setting up an animation sequence in jQuery on some tabbed HTML content.

Example HTML

```
<div id="tabs-2">
            <h2 class="majorpt">Pekinese</h2>
            <p class="minorpt">Tiramisu jujubes bear </p> 
            <h2 class="majorpt">Rottweiler</h2>
            <p class="minorpt">Tart bear claw biscuit </p>
        </div>
```

When a tab is clicked on, I want to fade in each `majorpt` class in sequence, followed by each `minorpt` class.

The code below works for majorpt class.

```
$("#tabs > ul > li > a").click( function (){
            $("#tabs > ul > li > a").css({ background: "#a2a2a2", color: "#cecece"});
            $(this).css({ background: "#eaeaea", color: "#333"});
            const thisTab = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#tabs > div:visible").fadeOut(200, function(){
                $(thisTab).fadeIn(200);
                $(thisTab+" .majorpt")
                    .each(
                        (function (index,element){
                        setTimeout(function (){
                                $(element).fadeIn(500); 
                        }, 1000 * index)
                        
                    })
                )
                
            });
            
        })
```

The challenge I have is then adding a similar function for the minorpt class:

```
            $(thisTab+" .minorpt").each(function (index,element){
                    setTimeout(function (){
                            $(element).fadeIn(500); 
                    }, 1000 * index)
                })
```

So far, every method I've tried to introduce this results in the animations all happening at the same time, or not happening at all due to botched syntax.

How do I queue these two loops so the second only happens once the first finishes?

Comment: Both `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` take a `callback` argument to run when it has completed, so sounds like you want `$(".majorop").fadeIn(() => $(".minoropt").fadeIn())`  - or adjust per "tab" to fit your existing code, eg `$(thisTab).fadeIn(200, function() { $(this).find(".minoropt").fadeIn())`

Comment: Or adjust your `1000 * index` to match the "parent" delay, eg `(1000*index) + (1000 * parentIndex)`

Comment: Yes, but where to put the call back? The complication is that the fadeIn() is inside an each() loop. If it were just one function running on one element, I'd have got this by now.

Comment: You currently have `$(thisTab).fadeIn(200);` - change to `$(thisTab).fadeIn(200, callback);`